# How to make sure that the column value is always added in Uppercase?

Tags: mysql, sql, calculated-columns, alter-table

I have an existing column `host` and want to make sure that the column value `host` is always added in `Uppercase`.

I am using `Alter Table` command as below:

```
ALTER TABLE `mydb`.`myTable` 
CHANGE COLUMN `host` `host`
VARCHAR(255) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (UPPER()) STORED;
```

This is causing an error and I am not able to alter the column.

> Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
> ERROR 1582: Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'UPPER'
> SQL Statement:
> ALTER TABLE `mydb`.`myTable`
> CHANGE COLUMN `host` `host` VARCHAR(255) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (UPPER()) VIRTUAL

I want to make sure that moving forward the value inserted in `host` is always in `uppercase`.
I want to achieve this by updating the value in `uppercase` at runtime.
I don't want to add any `constraint` as it will cause an error when the `host` value is entered in `lowercase`.

Comment: Does it matter?

Comment: Add a trigger which UPPERs

Comment: I want to make sure that moving forward the value inserted in `host` is always in `uppercase`.
I want to achieve this by updating the value in `uppercase` at runtime.
I don't want to add any `constraint` as it will cause an error when the `host` value is entered in `lowercase`.

Comment: Did you read my comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what you are trying to do.

If you want to set a constraint on the table that allows only upper case letters in `host`, use a check constraint:

```
alter table mytable
    add constraint chk_host_upper
    check (host rlike '^[A-Z]*$')
;
```

This prevents lower case character to be written to the column; an attempt to do so results in a runtime error.

If, on the other hand, you want to create a new column, that returns the upper case value of `host`, regardless of the actual column code:

```
alter table mytable
     add column host_upper varchar(50)  -- same as the original column
     as (upper(host))
;
```

With this set up at hand, you can query the new column `host_upper` when you want the upper case values.

---

Finally: if you want to convert input value to upper case on the fly on `insert`s, then you need a trigger:

```
delimiter //

create trigger mytrigger
before insert on mytable
for each row
begin
    set new.host = upper(new.host);
end
//
```

delimiter ;

Comment: I want to make sure that moving forward the value inserted in `host` is always in `uppercase`.
I want to achieve this by updating the value in `uppercase` at runtime.
I don't want to add any `constraint` as it will cause an error when the `host` value is entered in `lowercase`.

Comment: @meallhour: this sounds like a trigger. See my update.

Answer (score 2):

You can just assign the `host` column to have a case insensitive collation:

```sql
ALTER TABLE mydb.myTable MODIFY host VARCHAR(255)
CHARACTER SET latin1
COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
```

Now the case of the `host` you use when inserting does not matter, and you may compare against this column using any case.  If you still need to *view* the `host` as uppercase, then just use `UPPER()`:

```sql
SELECT UPPER(host) AS host_upper
FROM myTable;
```

Comment: I want to make sure that moving forward the value inserted in `host` is always in `uppercase`.
I want to achieve this by updating the value in `uppercase` at runtime.
I don't want to add any `constraint` as it will cause an error when the `host` value is entered in `lowercase`.

Comment: ...and my answer solves your problem, because it eliminates your need entirely to manage the case of the `host`.